# Css mode break indent region for javascript-mode

Tags: javascript, css

I have css-mode and javascript-mode and if I open css file the `indent-region-function` is set to `css-indent-region` which break javascript-mode indent region, how can I fix that? the workaround is to execute:

```
(setq indent-region-function nil)
```

after I switch to css-mode, is there a way to fix this without this hack?

Calling this:

```
(defun css-indent-mode-fix ()
  (setq indent-region-function nil))

(add-hook 'css-mode-hook 'css-indent-mode-fix)
```

Disable indent region in css mode.

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to do, could you provide a more concrete example?

Comment: @JordonBiondo If I open css file and switch to javascript file the indent region don't work, I still have `css-indent-region` in `indent-region-function` variable.

Comment: Does this happen with emacs -Q? The function `css-indent-region` does not exist for me, it may be coming from somewhere else. What version of emacs are you using?

Comment: @JordonBiondo It work fine with `emacs -Q`, the problem was my css-mode version 0.3 that was created by Alex Shinn, instead of build in emacs css-mode.